# How to fix Python: Mac OS X. malloc error?

Tags: python, malloc

Running Python 3.6.11

macOS Big Sur 11.1

I get the error below when running my project:

`python(4678,0x70000fd8b000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc0e3c607a0: pointer being freed was not allocated`

`python(4678,0x70000fd8b000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I don't have more information since this error started suddenly. I have no idea what could be causing it or how to debug it.

Any help that can put me in the right direction or on how to debug this is appreciated.